# Groupby sentiment labels by hour on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, group-by

I have a dataframe with three column structure:

| id | date | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1471249304341856262 | 2021-12-15 23:59:52 | POS |
| 1471249123341851422 | 2021-12-15 21:51:12 | NEU |
| 1471243214341856432 | 2021-12-15 20:26:11 | POS |
| 1471239304341874523 | 2021-12-15 19:39:44 | NEG |

label is about sentiment of a specific conversation (id), it can be NEU (Neutral), POS (Positive) or NEG (Negative).

I would like to groupby by hour, getting the absolute number of labels each hour, for example:

| date | POS | NEG | NEU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 232 | 424 | 311 |
| 2021-10-01 01:00:00 | 412 | 235 | 302 |
| 2021-10-01 02:00:00 | 123 | 323 | 643 |
| 2021-10-01 03:00:00 | 523 | 132 | 423 |

I tried something like this:

```py
df2 = df.resample('H', on='date').agg({'label':'count'})
```

But it counts all labels together, not splitted by them.

Q1: How can i get the count of labels by hours?
Q2: Is possible to get counted by % of each label by hours too?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=df['date'], columns=df['label'], values=df['id'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

output:

```
>>
label                date  NEG  NEU  POS
0     2021-12-15 19:00:00  1.0  0.0  0.0
1     2021-12-15 20:00:00  0.0  0.0  1.0
2     2021-12-15 21:00:00  0.0  1.0  0.0
3     2021-12-15 23:00:00  0.0  0.0  1.0
```